# Есть ли у меня здесь ошибка

Tags: c#

Скажите, у меня есть TextBox, в нём я хочу вводить пороль и передавать значения в переменную типа int... правильно ли составил код?

```
int pass;

int.TryParse(textPassword.Text, out pass);
```

*textPassword = Это TextBox

Comment: по-моему лучше использовать ``Convert.ToInt32()``

Comment: Вообще-то нет, в случае с классом `Convert` нужно еще обрабатывать исключения. И то и то имеют право на жизнь, но имхо лучше использовать средства, которые помогают избежать исключений. В данном случае, если нужно просто переконвертировать значение не выясняя причин, почему конверсия может упасть - лучше использовать TryParse, если нужно, чтобы метод бросил исключение и обработать какую-то ситуацию (специфичную по роду исключения) - тогда использовать методы класса `Convert`

Comment: если необходимо чтобы значение было числовым, а пользователь ввёл что-то другое, то его по-любому надо оповестить об этом, и бработка исключения брошеного Convert`ом как раз для этого!

Comment: А этом случае у меня такая ошибка "Входная строка имела неверный формат." Если использовать Convet.ToInt32();

Answer (score 1):

Код ок.
Само применение

```
int.TryParse(string s, out int result)
```

правильное.

Comment: **facepalm**, спасибо запомню.

Comment: Как правило, TryParse используется в сочетании с возвращаемым значением из функции для того, чтобы корректно обработать ситуации, когда конверсия падает.